# How can I add an icon to Material UI Select options?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to add icons inside `Select` options? I tried many times but none of them are working:

```
<option value={0}>&#xf083;Item One</option>
<option value={1}>
  <i class="fas fa-expand" />
  Item two
</option>
```

Full sample code:

```
class IconInSelect extends Component {
  state = {
    value: 0
  };
  handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value });
  };
  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <Select
        autoWidth
        native
        value={value}
        onChange={this.handleChange("value")}
        name="value"
        variant="filled"
        classes={{
          root: classes.selectEmpty,
          select: classes.select
        }}
      >
        <option value={0}>&#xf083;Item One</option>
        <option value={1}>
          <i class="fas fa-expand" />
          Item two
        </option>
        <option value={2}>Item three</option>
      </Select>
    );
  }
}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pp61kkr20j)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/91q9lyn274

Comment: no it seems option tag dont have way to render it when I converted to menuItem its working Thanks to @zoltan And Dennis

Comment: Remember to accept the answer below.

Comment: yea I did and it seem MenuItem conflict with native select for some reasons

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [MenuItem](https://material-ui.com/demos/menus/#customized-menuitem).

```js
class IconInSelect extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <Select>
        <MenuItem value="">
          <ListItemIcon>
            <InboxIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Inbox" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there are way to do this without all that space to the right of the icon?

Comment: the select component is empty. can you fix this. I tried your code. It works but the select component sown icon and text vertically after selection

Comment: Is there any way to locate one icon at the left on the input (not the options)?

Answer (score 14):

This works better without line-break when selected

```
<MenuItem value={10}>
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <InboxIcon />
        <div>Inbox</div>
    </div>
</MenuItem>
```

Just use custom styling in InboxIcon and set margin according to your need

Answer (score 3):

Dennis's asnwer works great for me but if you want to change the space between the icon and the text, use the code below:

```
import MuiMenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import AccessTimeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AccessTime';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const MenuItem = styled(MuiMenuItem)(({ theme }) => ({
  '& .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}));
```

```
<Select {...}>
  {names.map((name) => (
    <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
      <AccessTimeIcon />
      {name}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</Select>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer from Dennis will cause a line-break and different spacings when selected.

```js
<Select
    // use SelectDisplayProps to correctly align icon+text when selected
    SelectDisplayProps={{
        style: {display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center'},
    }}
>
    {options.map(option =>
        <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {/* the minWidth is applied by style in Menu, but not when selected */}
            <ListItemIcon sx={{minWidth: 36}}>
                <option.icon/>
            </ListItemIcon>
            {/* the menu text has no gutters by default, but ListItemText has */}
            <ListItemText primary={option.value} sx={{my: 0}}/>
        </MenuItem>,
    )}
</Select>
```