# How to properly add icon to select options in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I was trying to set an icon for each Select option in Material UI. I followed the answer proposed in this question [How can I add an icon to Material UI Select options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56115799/) using `ListItemIcon` and `ListItemText`, and it indeed shows the icon for each option but, when selected, the icon is shown alongside the option value on a different line. The image shows what I mean by this.

[image: Example of icon and text value once the option is selected]

What can I do to make it so that just the text is shown in one single line and no icon is displayed when I select an option? I'll attach here the code that I used for reference.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Box,
  Select,
  MenuItem,
  ListItemIcon,
  ListItemText,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import ShortTextIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ShortText";
import SubjectIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Subject";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [state, setState] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setState(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Box component="div" className={classes.root}>
      <Select value={state} onChange={handleChange}>
        <MenuItem value="First Choice">
          <ListItemIcon>
            <ShortTextIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="First Choice" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="Second Choice">
          <ListItemIcon>
            <SubjectIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Second Choice" />
        </MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `renderValue` property of [Select API](https://material-ui.com/api/select/#select-api) it allows you to render whatever you want as a value with signature: `function(value: any) => ReactNode` where `value` is current selected value of select. (This can be used only if `native` prop is `false`)